# How to align a GridView with different numbers of rows inside a DataList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm developing a web application where users can register expenses and I have a page where I show a report of all the registers per day and these registers come from database.
To show these registers, I have a DataList in which the days are displayed, and below this, a GridView to display the registers.

Supposing that the user registered different numbers of expenses in different days, if I show the report to the user, the GridView is totally misaligned, because of the different number of rows; basically, I have a thing like this:

[image: schematic drawing of problem]

Is there some way to align the GridView to show the registers aligned?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to replicate your issue on my side.All I did to fix it was to add this style rule to my page:

```
td
{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Below is the complete example of displaying a GridView inside a DataList in ASP.NET web forms with alignment fixed.

**Code behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication6
{
    public partial class DataListAndGrid : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("ID", typeof(String)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Day", typeof(String)));

            AddRow("0", "MONDAY", dt);
            AddRow("1", "TUESDAY", dt);
            AddRow("2", "WEDNESDAY", dt);
            AddRow("3", "THURSDAY", dt);
            AddRow("4", "FRIDAY", dt);
            AddRow("5", "SATURDAY", dt);
            AddRow("6", "SUNDAY", dt);

            daysOfWeek.DataSource = dt;
            daysOfWeek.DataBind();
        }

        private void AddRow(string id, string day, DataTable dt)
        {
            DataRow row;
            row = dt.NewRow();
            row[0] = id;
            row[1] = day;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        private void BindGrid(GridView gv, int id)
        {
            gv.DataSource = this.GetRegisters(id);
            gv.DataBind();
        }

        protected void daysOfWeek_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
        {
            object dataKey = daysOfWeek.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex];

            int key = Convert.ToInt32(dataKey);

            GridView gridResponses = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("gvResponses");
            BindGrid(gridResponses, key);
        }

        public List<Register> GetRegisters(int id)
        {
            List<Register> registers = new List<Register>();
            registers.Add(new Register() { DayID = 0, FirstName = "Monday Name 1", LastName = "Monday Surname 1" });
            registers.Add(new Register() { DayID = 0, FirstName = "Monday Name 2", LastName = "Monday Surname 2" });
            registers.Add(new Register() { DayID = 1, FirstName = "Tuesday Name 1", LastName = "Tuesday Surname 1" });
            registers.Add(new Register() { DayID = 1, FirstName = "Tuesday Name 1", LastName = "Tuesday Surname 2" });

            return registers.Where(r => r.DayID == id).ToList();
        }
    }

    public class Register
    {
        public int DayID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ASPX:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DataListAndGrid.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication6.DataListAndGrid" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #dayContainer {
            width: 250px;
            height: 70px;
            font-size: 20px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            display:table-cell;
        }

        #gridContainer {
            border: 2px solid black;
            border-top: none;
            width: 250px;
        }

        td
        {
            vertical-align:top;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:DataList ID="daysOfWeek" DataKeyField="ID" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnItemDataBound="daysOfWeek_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div style="float:left;">
                        <div id="dayContainer">
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Day") %>
                        </div>
                        <div id="gridContainer">
                            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvResponses" DataKeyNames="DayID" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" HeaderStyle-Width="125px" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" HeaderStyle-Width="125px" />
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image: Data List]